# laravel how to get all nested relation to a collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

So lets say i have a post which belong to 1 user which belong to 1 group;

now I getting all the posts:

```
$posts = Post::inCategory(1)->with('user','user.group')->get();
```

now I need to see all groups in the above query, is there some simple 1 liner collection trick to extract them? without looping like:

```
$groups = [];
foreach ($posts as $post){
 $groups[] = $post->user->group;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pluck` method,

`$groups = Post::inCategory(1)->with('user','user.group')->get()->pluck('user.group')->all()`